# setRelativeRedirectsAllowed() in RequestConfig apache-httpclient 5.x

Tags: java, spring, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpclient-5.x

I was migrating the usage of apache httpclient 4.x to httpclient 5.x version and there a lot of changes in the classes and methods. This particular question is about setRelativeRedirectsAllowed() method that was present in RequestConfig class upto 4.x version. As I am moving httpclient 5.x . I was not able to find the suitable replacement for it.

```
final RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig
          .custom()
          .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD)
          .setConnectionRequestTimeout(...)
          .setConnectTimeout(...)
          .setRedirectsEnabled(true)
          .setRelativeRedirectsAllowed(true)
          .setSocketTimeout(...)
          .build();

final CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder
          .create()
          .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
          .build()

final HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
```

I have provided the sample example of how we are using it in our code.

I have tried going through the [migration document](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.3.x/migration-guide/migration-to-classic.html), there was not any mention of it. I also looked at the code of apache-httpcomponents 4.x and spring 5.3.x to see if I could find how exactly it was being used, I couldn't.

My questions are,
Is there a suitable replacement present for that method (setRelativeRedirectsAllowed()) in httpclient 5.x,
If not, is there a way to custom implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need anything as a replacement. It supports both relative and absolute redirects out-of-the-box now. This has been addressed in [this commit](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/commit/777f6ead467639563df7a5cdbb6b824c47108aec) (you gotta love some code archaeology :) ).

So in short there is no replacement and relative redirects should just work (tm).